# "Hope it's over" vs "Hope it gets over"

Tags: causative-get

I was talking to a friend about Covid, and I told him how everyone is tired of it, and I wanted to express a wish about hopping for it to come to an end soon. Now, I'm wondering if there's any difference between the two:

> Hope it's over soon.

> Hope it gets over soon.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are really correct, as the best for, is probably

> Hope it’ll be over soon.

“It’s over” suggests something in the present, but that’s not accurate for the verb “is.” In other words, as @stangdon mentioned, you can use the structure “Hope [pronoun] [simple present tense] soon for most verbs, but NOT for the verb “is,” which is used to describe states of being rather than actions.

“It gets over” is not an idiomatic phrase in English; “get over” can be used to mean “overcome,” but you’d see it more in a context like

> Hope she’s able to get over him soon.

Things like global pandemics aren’t exactly things you “get over,” in my opinion.

Comment: I have to disagree with you about "It's over" necessarily suggesting something in the present.  We often use the present tense with plans or hopes for the future, as in "My father's ship arrives tomorrow", or ["I hope she recovers soon", which you can find numerous live examples of.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22i+hope+she+recovers+soon%22&biw=1343&bih=736&tbm=bks&ei=IYAOYqygHcbKytMP7Lqc0As&ved=0ahUKEwjstPuUnIf2AhVGpXIEHWwdB7oQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=%22i+hope+she+recovers+soon%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQjANYjANg4wVoAHAAeACAAT-IAXuSAQEymAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Comment: I would also disagree with "Hope it’ll be over soon." being the "best" way to convey this... I personally would say "I hope it ends soon." And, I believe that is how most native AmE speakers would say it.

Comment: @stangdon You’re right; I’ll edit my response to reflect that.

Comment: @EliHarold I disagree with you on that one; I’ve certainly heard both used before, in roughly equal contexts, and I am an AmE speaker. In fact, I would personally use my example over “Hope it ends soon.” I also believe “Hope it’ll be over soon” to be the closest equivalent to their original sentence, and thus went with that as my suggestion.

Comment: @AnnabethYeung I am a native AmE speaker as well, maybe this depends on location. In south USA "I hope it all ends soon" or "I can't want until this is over." tends to be what is used from my experience.